# I'm trying to receive a webhook from an Autodesk Forge workflow.transition event but they aren't firing

Tags: webhooks, autodesk-forge

I've been experimenting with the Fusion Lifecycle webhooks in Forge and have been successful using the item created/updated events but the workflow transition webhooks aren't firing.

The webhooks are created in Forge according to the [Docs](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/webhooks/v1/reference/events/workflow.transition/), as you can see below, but none of the transitions performed in the workspace will trigger the call.

They were created using a three-legged token associated with a Fusion Lifecycle user that has the proper workflow permissions on the workspace.

The following JSON excerpt is the workflow. transition webhook as returned from developer.api.autodesk.com/webhooks/v1/hooks endpoint on Forge showing it was indeed created.

​
    `{
      "hookId": "909fd040-4e34-11ea-a842-651c9013b5e8",
      "tenant": "TENANTNAMEREMOVED4SO",
      "callbackUrl": "callbackurl removed for SO",
      "createdBy": "46FGNL6DBN6D",
      "event": "workflow.transition",
      "createdDate": "2020-02-13T07:43:45.988+0000",
      "system": "adsk.flc.production",
      "creatorType": "O2User",
      "status": "active",
      "scope": {
        "workflow.transition": "urn:adsk.plm:tenant.workspace.workflow.transition:TENANTNAMEREMOVED4SO.119.1.765"
      },
      "hookAttribute": {
        "creator": "D3 Forge Playground",
        "notification": {
          "class": "alert-danger",
          "system": "flc"
        }
      },
      "urn": "urn:adsk.webhooks:events.hook:909fd040-4e34-11ea-a842-651c9013b5e8",
      "__self__": "/systems/adsk.flc.production/events/workflow.transition/hooks/909fd040-4e34-11ea-a842-651c9013b5e8"
    }`

I've pushed the workflow through the transition events numerous times and no webhook is being fired and no failed requests on our webhook receiving server either. if I mimic the payload for the workflow. transition event and post it to our endpoint, it is received as expected.

I have yet to see a live example of the workflow. transition webhook being fired and can't find any sample code from Autodesk using them. Not sure the service is even working as expected at this point even though the item.created and item.updated webhook events seem to work fine.

Has anyone successfully received a workflow. transition webhook from Autodesk Forge? If yes, could you provide some guidance on how?

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be working fine on my end in a Production tenant. This is the payload I used to create the webhook:

```
{
    "callbackUrl": "https://webhook.site/SOME_ID",
    "scope": {
        "workflow.transition": "urn:adsk.plm:tenant.workspace.workflow.transition:TENANT.107.1.421"
    }
}
```

Does it look like the payload you used when creating the hook?

Comment: Indeed it does. The workflow transition webhooks are also returned from the 'list webhooks' endpoints with status of active.

Answer (score 0):

Greg, any chance you can try to trigger it again, and send me the date/time stamp with tenant name via a private message? I just tried it again in my Production tenant, and it seems to be working just fine when I perform the operation from both a v3 API call, and the UI. Feel free to file a support case if you want, too, and let me know the case number. I'd like to help you out here in understanding what's going on, because overall it looks OK from your side.

Comment: Thanks Giliar, I filed a case (5745) already. The case included the tenant info but I have since removed the hook from forge. I will gladly recreate the hook and retrigger it (while capturing timestamps) so we can get to the bottom of this. I'll get it done and send to you asap, Thanks again.